# Windows 7 Windows Explorer jumpy tree view

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, tree-view

Is there any way to get Windows Explorer tree view in Windows 7 to stop jumping? I think they really messed up this design. Click a node to expand a deeper level and it instantly scrolls the tree vertically to a new location. This is not a good feature since my eye completely loses the node it was focused on and I have to hunt for where I was. I want the tree view to remain fixed where it is unless I scroll it myself.

Comment: I feel your pain.  It bugs me as well.  I haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I turned off "Automatically expand to current folder" in folder options. This is good enough for now.

Comment: that doesnt seem to work all the time - I cant quite put my finger on when it decides to do it anyway but this is still a problem in windows 8

Comment: At least in Windows 10, it seems to expand folders even with the checkbox unchecked when the current folder already shows up in the navigation pane and you then navigate to a subfolder.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution would be to move to an Explorer-alternative, of which there are [heaps](http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/11/10-windows-explorer-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/).

Comment: I tried xplorer2 lite for a while and went back to windows explorer on vista. The problem is they may not have shell integration like windows explorer. No tortoiseSVN, no winzip, that sort of thing. And some of these add too much -- editors, preview, etc.

Comment: Almost all of them have shell integration. My own favorite is the free Servant Salamander 1.52 : http://www.altap.cz/download.html#salrel. Although not the most jazzy, it's very functional.

Comment: xplorer2 definitely has full shell integration. If you're on x64, you need to run the x64 version of xplorer2.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second xplorer2.  I purchased the license for it and use it more frequently than Explorer (I use both for this and that).  And shell integration in Windows 7 is supported regardless of your bitness, though there is a "trick".  If you right-click and don't see the menu items you're looking for, look for the Explorer item and expand that.  That's where the rest of the shell extensions are hiding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old, but still annoying issue.  I found that if you remove libraries from appearing in the Windows Shell... the jumping is gone, except when there is a large number of subfolders, then Explorer relocates the parent folder up so you can see more subfolders.  But no more jumping down in the pane.  [Instructions on how to remove libraries from the Explorer](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/35627-libraries-folder-add-remove-navigation-pane.html)